# What's the volume of $\{x\in[0,1]^n|\sum x_i\le t\}$ for real $t$?

Tags: convex-polytopes, hypercube

EDIT: Thanks for your answers and comments. There is indeed a classical easy formula, given by Pietro Majer (with a simple nice proof) in his answer below.

---

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_i$ denotes its $i$-th coordinate. My question is:

- What is $Vol(\{x\in[0,1]^n|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\le t\})$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ ? Is there some kind of "easily computable" formula for it ?

A colleague asked me this in relation to a problem in applied mathematics, and I thought that the answer was going to be easy to find, but after trying to compute it by hand in dimension $3$ and then generalizing, I just surrendered. I am pretty sure that it should be somehow classical, but I could not track down a formula or a reference in the general case. I should specify that I know next to nothing about section of convex bodies, and I might be missing something easy. With some browsing, I found the following partial answers (which I hope I do not mix-up):

- If $t$ is an integer, then the volume is the sum of the $t$ first Eulerian numbers divided by $n!$.
- Between and integer $t<n$ and the next, the volume function is a polynomial of degree $n$. The polynomials corresponding to two consecutive intervals must have the same first derivative at their common point. For instance, for $n=2$ the volume is given by $\frac{t^2}{2}$ if $t\in[0,1]$, $1 - \frac{(2-t)^2}{2}$ for $t\in[1,2]$ and constant elsewhere.
- There is a Fourier-analysis approach for the problem of finding the $n-1$-volume of the section of a convex body by an hyperplane, but the formulas I found did not seem to me easily computable (my knowledge of Fourier analysis is approximatively equivalent to that of convex bodies, I must say).
- We can use some probability theory to find an approximation: each $x_i$ is seen as a random variable following a law of mean $\mu$ and variance $\nu$, then $S=\sum x_i$ follows (approximatively  and for large $n$) the normal law with mean $n\mu$ and variance $n^2\nu$, and the probability of $S\le t$ is then easy to compute. I presume that the meaning of "$n$ is large" and "approximate" can be made explicit by looking more closely at the central limit theorem. (This idea comes from Michael Lugo's answer to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22648/area-of-cross-section-at-midpoint-perpendicular-to-longest-diagonal-in-the-uni/22670#22670). Another answer by Andrey Rekalo points to the Fourier-analysis method mentioned above.)

The last point brings a more general question: given a probability distribution on $[0,1]$ (perhaps in some well behaved class), are there some good estimates for $P(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\le t)$ for smaller $n$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you find this paper and its references useful: http://analytic-combinatorics.org/index.php/ojac/article/view/26

Comment: Thanks Moritz, I'll look at it. At first glance it seems quite useful indeed.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145475/ appears to be true in this case: D. L. Barrow and P. W. Smith, Spline notation applied to a volume problem, Amer. Math. Monthly, 86 (1979) (I haven't check this reference yet..)

Comment: If you remove the condition that the $x_i$ are bounded above by 1 then the volume of this region is a standard result in algebraic number theory: the volume is $t^n/n!$. So that formula works if $t \leq 1$ when you insist $x_i \in [0,1]$.  Details of the calculation can be found in Lemma 7.17 (p. 159) of Frazer Jarvis's Algebraic Number Theory and Lemma 3 of Section 3 of Chapter V of Lang's Algebraic Number Theory (set $r_2 = 0$ in both cases).

Comment: This is the Irwin-Hall distribution; there are indeed formulas in Wikipedia.

Comment: I just noticed that I forgot to thank Kevin for the name of this distribution, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The volume $V_n(t)$ is the cdf of the sum of $n$ independent random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. So the density $V_n'(t)$ is the $n$-fold convolution of the characteristic function of the unit interval, $\chi_{[0,1]}$. (In particular  $V_n'\in C^{n-2,1}(\mathbb{R})$, with support in $[0,n]$, and polynomial of degree less than $ n $ on any interval between consecutive integers). It is convenient to write $\chi_{[0,1]}(t)=H(t)-H(t-1)$, where $H(t):=\chi_{\mathbb{R_+}}(t)$ is the Heaviside function, or $\chi_{[0,1]}=H-\tau^1 H$
where $\tau^s:f\mapsto f(\cdot-s)$ is the translation semigroup on functions. Recall that convoluting with $H$ is taking a primitive: $(H*f)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$, so in particular $H^{*(n+1)}(t)=t_+^n/n!$, and that $\tau^s(f*g)=\tau^sf*g= f* \tau^s g$.

Thus $$V_n=H*V'_n=H*(H-\tau^1H)^{*n}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}H*H^{*(n-k)}*(\tau^1H)^{*k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k} \tau^kH^{*(n+1)},$$ 
that is $$V_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!} {(t-k)_+}{^n}\, .$$

Comment: Which, in the language of a school kid, is just PIE: take the simplex $S=\{x_i>0, \sum x_i<t\}$ and its translates $S_j$ by $n$ unit vectors. We want $v(S\setminus\cup (S\cap S_j)$ and the volumes of $S\cap (S_{j_1}\cap\dots\cap S_{j_k})$ are exactly $\frac 1{n!}(t-k)_+^n$.

Comment: When I was a school kid, PIE was something to eat. Later when I took linguisitcs PIE was Proto-Indo-European. I don't think I've seen PIE as an abbreviation for the principle of inclusion-exclusion before. In what areas of math is that abbreviation widely used?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I finished texting it occurred to me there is this more geometrical and more elementary interpretation: write the characteristic function of the cube as a convenient linear combination of $[0,+\infty)^n$ and its translates, then integrating over $\sum_j x_j\le t$.

Comment: btw, I also use PIE as short form of my personal name.

Comment: @KConrad Almost every English-speaking school kid who took part in some math olympiads would call it this way. Just go to AoPS and check if you do not want to take my word for it :-).

Comment: This is the Irwin-Hall distribution.

Comment: @fedja: After posting my previous comment I had found PIE on the Art of Problem Solving website. Is it used by anyone in research papers, where abbreviations like PID, UFD, and DVR are common?

Comment: @KConrad Who knows? Usually the guys you are thinking of call it "sieve methods" and other fancy names specific to the particular branches of math. they are doing, but I would certainly refer to it as PIE myself if I ever needed to apply it in one of my own papers. :-)

Comment: (If I had to name it only once or twice in a paper, I'd use the extended form. If I had to use it ten times in a page, I'd use the acronym, possibly clarifying it the first time. I guess that's what everybody does with every phrase to be repeated).

Comment: (On a side note, there is a principle of inclusion and exclusion, also related with processes of integration, even in Anthropology and Social Sciences. I believe that it shows in MO not less than its mathematical cousin)